# How to use GSON with Java modules

Tags: gson, java-module

I have three modules, client, server and common.  The common module consists entirely of POJO models.

So in common module I have a model defined like so (simplified), note BaseModel is a class that contains common audit elements like creation datetime, etc., you should be able to exclude it:

```
package model;

public class User extends BaseModel
{
    private String user, user_id;
    
    public String getUser() {       return user;    }
    public void setUser(String user)    {       this.user = user;   }
    public String getUser_id()  {       return user_id; }
    public void setUser_id(String user_id)  {       this.user_id = user_id; }
}
```

I am attempting to request a list of users, the response is put in a class defined only in the client module like this:

```
package control.model;

import java.util.List;

public class Response<T>
{
    private String status;
    private List<T> response;

    public String getStatus()   {       return status;  }
    public void setStatus(String status)    {       this.status = status;   }
    public List<T> getResponse()    {       return response;    }
    public void setResponse(List<T> list)   {       this.response = list;   }
}
```

The server module creates the JSON response like so:

```
private static String RESP = "{\"status\":\"%s\", \"response\":%s}";

List<User> users = get from database in the server module.
String resp = String.format(RESP, "PASS", new Gson().toJson(users));
```

The module definition for common follows:

```
module inventoryCommon
{
    requires transitive javafx.base;
    exports model;
    opens model to gson;
}
```

The module definition for client follows:

```
module fileManager
{
    requires transitive java.sql;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires transitive javafx.controls;
    
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires inventoryCommon;
    
    requires gson;
    requires transitive Java.WebSocket;
    
    exports control;
    
    exports ui to javafx.graphics;
    
    opens control.model to gson;
}
```

Inside my client class (also inside the client module) I try to parse the response like so:

```
Response<User> response = new Gson().fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

Here is a sample of the value of the String json:

```
{"status":"PASS", "response":[{"user":"Me","user_id":"ME123"}, {"user":"You","user_id":"YOU456"}]}
```

Everything looks fine to me but I am getting this exception which seems to indicate that the problem is the class User is in a different module from where I try to parse it from?

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class model.User (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap is in module gson@2.4 of loader 'app'; model.User is in module inventoryCommon of loader 'app')

If you require more details let me know.

PS My code is based on what I read in this article:
[tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-arrays-and-lists-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSON needs more type information that it can't get from the syntax you used. It uses TypeToken to extract that generic information into something it can use to help instantiate your Response POJO's structure.

I successfuly replicated your issue on my side using just 3 classes (Response, User and a class to test Deserializing them, TestModel) and saw the LinkedTreeMaps (GSON's best closest metaphor to creating a type when it doesn't have enough type info for a complex Object) being created.

By adding the TypeToken definition, I was able to get it to deserialize to your User object just fine. Here is a sample test I wrote that fixes it.

```
package control.model;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class TestModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\"status\":\"PASS\", \"response\":[{\"user\":\"Me\",\"user_id\":\"ME123\"}, {\"user\":\"You\",\"user_id\":\"YOU456\"}]}";

        TypeToken<Response<User>> typeToken = new TypeToken<Response<User>>() {} ;
        Response<User> response = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeToken.getType());

        // Run this in DEBUG mode and put a breakpoint in to look at the type of object in "response.getResponse()". Should be an array of USER now, not LinkedTreeMaps...
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + response.getResponse());
    }

}
```